# Rename HTML name attribute to get data into model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have problems to pass data from a form using post into my model.

I have the following code:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    ...
    return this.View("Edit", Tuple.Create(staff, team);
}
```

As you can see I am returning a Tuple to the View, because I need to have more than one model. I guess I would normally create a ViewModel, but in this case this would be to much I think.
Is there generally something wrong returning a Tuple, List, or even a Dictionary to a View? Should I always create a ViewModel?

This is the View:

```
@model Tuple<Staff, List<Team>>
@{
    var staff = Model.Item1;
    var teams = Model.Item2;
}

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
    @Html.LabelFor(model => staff.Foo)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => staff.Bar)
}

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
    @Html.LabelFor(model => team.Foo)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => team.Bar)
}
```

Anyway, this code renders like so:

```
<input type="text" ... name="staff.Foo" ... />
```

and

```
<input type="text" ... name="team.Foo" ... />
```

This is my target controller (when I submit form "staff"):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "foo,bar")] Staff staff)
{
   ...
   this.DbContext.SaveChanges();
   ...
}
```

The problem is, that the data will be send via post, but my models keeps beeing empty. I guess this is due to the fact I passed my models as a Tuple to the view.
Even though I change

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item1.Foo)
```

will be

```
<input type="text" ... name="Item1.Foo" ... />
```

How can I fix this. I couln't find a solution to rename the name attribute to simply "Foo" instead of "staff.Foo". I guess this would fix the problem. Do I really have to create a ViewModel?

Best regards

Comment: Out of interest, have you tried `public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "foo,bar")] Staff item1)`?

Comment: The HTML helpers `EditorFor` etc work on the assumption that you will rebind them on submit using the model defined in your view. If  this is not what you want, just write out the `<input>` manually. Or if tjhings are getting messy, create a ViewModel like you suggested in the first place

Comment: @AdrianWragg no, I tried it just now, but it didn't work. I cheated above (sorry), actually instead of `public ActionResult ... Staff staff`, it was `public ... Staff someGerman`, as I changed it to `Staff staff`, it worked right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only posting one complex property of the model/tuple, you can use the `Bind.Prefix` property

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Prefix="staff")] Staff model)
```

This effectively strips the `staff.` prefix from the properties so `staff.Foo` becomes `Foo` and will be bound to class `Staff`, however I strongly recommend using a view model rather than `Tuple` (and its actually less code anyway).

Comment: Hi, this works. Thank you very much. I guess I should create the ViewModel, it is much cleaner I guess. I am very new to .NET so thank you very much for clearing that up for me.